# Get file system by angularjs or jquery

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, filesystems

I'm using **angularjs** and **spring**  framework to generate **jasper report** and save report to file system by

```
 File newFile = new File("/home/person/report");
```

So the reports saved automatically to this path.

What I want to do is, make update that let user choose the path of the report by dialog box that enables user to navigate the local file system and select the desired path.

I want to get the path from angular and send it by REST service.

Comment: You can't access user directory paths for obvious security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Accessing files directly is not supported.

If you insist doing that you can write a browser extension that does these operations or porting your web to a native-web application using frameworks like [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron)

#### However,

You can (and should) use file uploads ...